# Isometry from higher to lower dimensions

Tags: metric-spaces

I was wondering if there was any isometry from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, using the Euclidean metric?

Answer (score 3):

no, in the real line, there are not three numbers at a common distance of $1$ apart for each pair. In the plane, there are equilateral triangles

Comment: could you explain what my teacher means then by this question , or is it a trick question .....Let X be a set and (M, d) be a metric space. Let           f : X→ M be an injective map. Then we define
f∗d := d ◦ (f × f): X × X →(0,inf), i.e.
f*d(x, y) = d(f(x), f(y)) for x, y ∈ X. Let d
denote the standard euclidean metric on R^k.Is there an injective map f : R^2 → R  such that d^2 = f∗d^1? Hint: Look at a triangle in R^2

Comment: @jamiemma1995 your $f^\ast$ is pulling back the metric on $M$ to  a metric on $X.$ Indeed, it is forcing $f$ to become an isometry. This means that there is no such map $f$ for $X = \mathbb R^2$ and $M = \mathbb R.$ No trick.

Answer (score 0):

An isometry would be both continuous and 1-1.  So, no way.